# Not able to run the jar file - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I have a jar file called 'TJXLineFilterPlugin'. Value of MANIFEST.MF is

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: c:\stdintjbt\java\lib\ojdbc14.jar c:\stdintjbt\java\lib\commons-lang-2.0.jar c:\stdintjbt\java\lib\jitterbit-plugin-sdk.jar c:\stdintjbt\java\lib\jitterbit-xml-utils.jar .
Created-By: 1.6.0_35 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: org.jitterbit.plugins.tjx.TJXLineFilterPlugin
```

Tried running

```
java -jar E:\TJXLineFilterPlugin.jar
```

There is a folder strucrure inside the jar is

```
org/jitterbit/plugins/tjx/TJXLineFilterPlugin.class
```

But it throw the error like,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jitterbit/plugins
/tjx/TJXLineFilterPlugin
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jitterbit.plugins.tjx.TJXLineFi
lterPlugin
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.jitterbit.plugins.tjx.TJXLineFilterPlugin. Pr
ogram will exit.
```

I tried running with class path `cp` also.

Comment: Please share the command that you used for running the jar file.

Comment: I pasted, please check it

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFoundError` usually means the class listed **was found** but could not be loaded because some of its dependencies could not be found.

I would point you to the `Class-Path` entry in your MANIFEST file:

```
Class-Path: ... c:\stdintjbt\java\lib\ojdbc14.jar .
```

First, you should liste the dependent JARs with paths relative to the JAR in question (your JAR), and not use absolute paths like you did.

Second, I don't think `.` should even be there because inner-JAR classpath is not the same as on-disk classpath where you are adding current working directory to the classpath with the `.`.

**UPDATE**

A Java application is usually delivered / deployed in a following structure:

```
myapp/
    applauncher (script or executable)
  + conf
  + logs
    lib/
       myapp.jar
       a.jar
       b.jar
       ...
```

For this example your `Class-Path` entry should be:

```
Class-Path: ojdbc14.jar commons-lang-2.0.jar jitterbit-plugin-sdk.jar jitterbit-xml-utils.jar
```

Comment: You mean to say that (relative path), I should copy the dependant jar files in the same directory as main jar file exists?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the specific directory containing the jar file and then execute the following command:

```
java -jar TJXLineFilterPlugin.jar
```

The path to specific class is always relative in your manifest. Executing the jar from different directory will not find the required classes.